# how to track messages on an outlook server

Tags: c#, java, process, windows-services, exchange-server

i'm writting a program, and some of its features is to track email messages sent to a specific email addresse.
the server is MS exchange, and i'm wondering how to make this feature. 
the purpose is :
whenever an email is sent to a specific addressse : admin@domain.com, this program will detect this, and grab the body, subject, and some basic properties like time date and priority.
is there any exchange API that could help me doing this ? thank you very much. the program is in c# language. any hint about libraries in .net or even java would be appreciated. Have a great Day !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the EWS Managed API. It allows you to access a mailbox.

Now, depending on your reaction time (time between message arrival and processing), you can either poll the mailbox from time to time and process all new mails. Or you can use push/pull/streaming subscriptions to get notifications about new mails. See my [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312849%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) on MSDN for a description of the different models.

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx